# Unable to change "Device in editor" in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I am unable to change nexus 4 to nexus 6 "device in editor" in android studio.When I select nexus 6, nothing happens. It is just stuck on nexus 4. Please help me to get through this !

Comment: I would strongly advice to look into AndroidStudio logs and if possible to add more details into the question. Right now it's more of an open ended question where multiple things could have gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it was resolved.

Comment: How did you resolve @deepansh?

Comment: that was nothing but incomplete loading of android studio on 4GB RAM laptop. When it was done, everything was right.